# kendo dropdownlist big list virtualization

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

Hello I'm using kendo dropdownlist object and have thousands of items in it.  To make it load fast, I saw I can use virtualization.

But how to use it with a local list?  The only example I can find is using that with web services.

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about doing it as an autocomplete?   I'm doing that with a list of 3000 entries.

Comment: Virtualization is diff from auto-complete, it loads fast plus shows items as well.I came here looking for same thing.